# Trying to compile a target. It is C code. Have put #ifdef MYDEBUG. How to pass it as set during compilation?

Tags: c, unix, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a target using make. In my code, I have put prepossessing conditionals as:

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
 (code to execute)
#endif
```

Now I was under the impression that if I do a

```
make -DMYDEBUG target
```

the code should get compiled. But this doesn't seem to be working. And I don't know whats going wrong and where. There are hierarchies of makefiles, which I have tried to look through, but frankly I don't know what I am looking for. Isn't the above supposed to work? Or MIGHT there be an option specified in the makefiles that disables setting the MYDEBUG variable as above? OR am I doing something else wrong? FYI my dev box is a freebsd.

Comment: Try `export CFLAGS=-DMYDEBUG` and do make. You need to pass `-D` to compiler.

Comment: Hey thanks! That seemed to work. But can you please explain, or point me to something which can help me understand this more. I want to know what the issue with "make -DMYDEBUG target" was, and what CFLAGS is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure option `-DMYDEBUG` to `make` works or does anything useful.

When you use `#ifdef MYDEBUG` you need `MYDEBUG` as defined pre-processor. This can be done in multiple ways.

- Define in code as `#define MYDEBUG`
- Ask compiler to define it, by specifying appropriate option. For `gcc` you can specify it with `-DMYDEBUG`.
- If written appropriately makefiles generally can also use environment variables defined, like `CFLAGS`, `LIBS` etc to pass to appropriate commands.
- `CFLAGS` is used to specify any compilation related options.

Comment: Yes well I did know I could just do a #define MYDEBUG, but wanted something without having to change the code. But this still leaves me wondering about the -D option in make. CFLAGS is good enough though.

Comment: The `-D` option to define a preprocessor macro is a compiler option.  Make is not a compiler, and it doesn't accept the same arguments or options as a compiler.  If you want to know what the `-D` option means to `make`, look at the documentation for your version of `make`.  The most common version of `make` on GNU/Linux systems, GNU make, for example, does not accept `-D` as a valid option and will give an error.

Comment: Technically you want to use `CPPFLAGS` for preprocessor options (the `PP` stands for "preprocessor") like `-D`, not `CFLAGS`.  But often both will work.